# How to merge two files with commit history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In our repository, we have some files that are exports from an application we use. Until recently, anytime a new export file was created, the file was copied/pasted into the repository and committed so the versioning and commit history were on the same file.

However, it appears as though someone copied/pasted the most recent export files to the repository with names that included a date (I supposed for extra versioning), added the files, and committed them, creating a separate version and commit history.

So, here's an example of what this looked like originally (the revision listed is the latest revision for the file):

```
Alfa.abc                 (Revision 100)
Bravo.abc                (Revision 135)
Charlie.abc              (Revision 117)
```

Here's an example of what it looks like now (the revision listed for the files with dates is the only revision for that file):

```
Alfa.abc                 (Revision 100)
Alfa_10052019.abc        (Revision 152)
Bravo.abc                (Revision 135)
Bravo_10062019.abc       (Revision 154)
Charlie.abc              (Revision 117)
Charlie_10012019.abc     (Revision 141)
Charlie_10102019.abc     (Revision 177)
```

So, in the 2nd example, `Charlie.abc` and `Charlie_10012019.abc` and `Charlie_10102019.abc` are different revisions and the incremental change from the revision that precedes it (177 is the revision of 141 is the revision of 117) even though they weren't versioned correctly.

Is there a way to merge these files together so there is only one `Charlie.abc` file that has all the previous revisions that `Charlie.abc` had plus the two new revisions from the files with dates (141, 177)? I know merge is probably not the right word to describe this, but hopefully my explanation makes sense.

If there's a way to fix this, then the log for `Charlie.abc` would look like the following after the fix:

```
Revision     Date          Message
88           09/27/2019    artifact #316     *This was an existing revision
117          09/29/2019    artifact #316
141          10/01/2019    artifact #316
177          10/10/2019    artifact #316
```

I'm a GUI user, so if there's a solution that uses the GUI, that would be ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's possible in Subversion but would having their differences merged manually be okay as an alternative solution?

1. Use `svn diff` or the Diff command in TortoiseSVN to find the differences between the original and the new files.
2. Manually add those differences to your original files which is basically merging them. If you want to use the GUI you can still use the same Diff window titled as TortoiseMerge to do that quickly.
3. Commit your modified files.
4. Depending on your needs you can delete those files with underscores or just unversion and add them to your ignore list.

I understand that would give you new commit dates and revision numbers but that might still be acceptable if nothing else works.